# Jewish Conversion?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

I am a man, 25 and I am Jewish. I have heard the calling of the one true and only God. I believe there is only one God and that the teachings of Judaism extend and assist in the life of Man in ways that are both carnal and beyond the scope of any man as such to understand but are applicable to mankind as a whole. I grew up under the yoke of Protestantism (Hispanic influenced Pentecostalism former Catholicism - though I have Sephardi roots) and though the teachings are in essence intertwined to a degree; I have always identified and aligned with Judaism. I have began to study Kabbalah (number theory aspect) and am learning Hebrew; My love of knowledge though always lead and associated me with Jews and the people of the likes. My surrogate father and family friend is Jewish and had much influence on me growing up - from him, a man of no children, I have learned much.

My question is how does my conversion process began and can one guide me.

Comment: Your first sentence says you are Jewish - if indeed your mother is Jewish there is no need for conversion. But you might have meant to write something else. In any case  [welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: You might be interested in many of our [tag:conversion-to-judaism] questions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Shalom Cameron Carter.

(1) Regarding conversion, I would recommend you approach your rabbi. He will tell you the steps to take. Tell him you have Jewish roots. That will help tremendously!

(2) I recommend Maimonides. I think rationalism is the best form of Judaism and the most correct. It is also the most tolerant.

Comment: Why is this so down voted?